# What do different HDR monitor support capabilities mean in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, hdr

In *Windows HD Color Settings* I can see three types of HDR support:
[image]

From hardware point of view, such distinction is quite strange, because it doesn't matter for monitor what type of content to display.

Moreover, YouTube streams in HDR in Edge unlike Chrome (and the difference is noticeable), so the display definitely supports at least some kind of HDR.

**So, is there some kind of hardware distinction, or is it just matter of drivers/settings/etc.? If the second is the case, are there any hacks to turn *Stream HDR video* capability into the other two?**

P.S. My device is Lenovo Yoga 720 15 4k version

Comment: Dell mentions that my display has Dolby Vision and supports 100% sRGB colors with the brightness of 300 nits, but windows says HDR is not supported and neither advanced color is supported. go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Windows versions do a very good job of detecting the capabilities of
the monitors.
HDR can get more vibrant, brighter and better-colored graphics for games,
apps and movies, but be aware that all non-HDR-ready content will appear
much more washed out on the color spectrum as a result.
**HDR requires that the PC, display, and display cable meet some requirements.**

To check if
[Wide Color Gamut (WCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-gamut_RGB_color_space)
is available on your monitor, go to
*Settings > System > Display > Windows HD Colour settings* and
click the link for "HDR and WCG settings".
If under the header "HDR and WCG" there is no "On" option or the link is not found,
then your monitor is not capable of an extended color gamut.

For more information, see the articles:

- [How to Enable HDR in Windows 10](https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-hdr-windows10/)
- [How to Turn On or Off HDR and WCG Color for a Display in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/120188-turn-off-hdr-wcg-color-display-windows-10-a.html).